# Checking for update of a file in gitlab project

Tags: javascript, node.js, gitlab, microservices, gitlab-api

I am writing a service with node.js, and depending on whether a file in my gitlab project has been recently updated or not, the way the service works will change. So how can I tell if the content of a file in my gitlab project has changed or not on the node.js service side? Is there a Gitlab API service for this?

Answer (score 1):

Gitlab does offer a robust API but could you not just run a git fetch and diff:

```
git fetch origin master
git diff origin/master:./ --compact-summary
```

That will list any files that have changed compared to your local. If you'd like to access that from Node you could put it in a shell script, run it as a spawned child_process and parse the stdout.

This method depends on your service checking for changes manually, if instead you want your service to be alerted when a change happens at any time you may want to look into webhooks: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/integrations/webhooks.html

Answer (score 1):

you can monitor (with a crontab) the [project's commits](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/commits.html#list-repository-commits) or with [webhooks](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/integrations/webhooks.html) (like @Dave said) and after that get commit diff info with [gitlab commit api](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/commits.html#get-the-diff-of-a-commit) to see if your file was modified